# In Corda, how to get the timestamp of when a transaction happened?

Tags: corda

I am using Corda 3.2. Given a `SignedTransaction`, how can I establish when it was recorded?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct API for determining when a transaction was recorded. However, you can achieve this by checking either:

1. When one of the transaction's inputs was consumed:

   ```
   val inputStateRef = signedTx.inputs[0]
   val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = listOf(inputStateRef))
   val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(queryCriteria)
   val consumedTime = results.statesMetadata.single().consumedTime!!
   ```
2. When one of the transaction's outputs was recorded:

   ```
   val ledgerTx = signedTx.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub)
   val outputStateRef = StateRef(signedTx.id, 0)
   val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = listOf(outputStateRef))
   val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(queryCriteria)
   val recordedTime = results.statesMetadata.single().recordedTime
   ```