# not able to whielist a class in corda 4?

Tags: corda

Hi I used this example https://docs.corda.net/serialization.html#whitelisting to whitelist a java.sql.timestamp class manually but still I get this error:

```
"No unique deserialisation constructor found for class class java.sql.Timestamp, type is marked as non-composable
E 10:05:59 80 SerializationOutput.log - Serialization failed direction="Serialize", type="java.sql.Timestamp", msg="Class "class java.sql.Timestamp" is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable.", ClassChain="java.util.List<*> -> java.sql.Timestamp"
   E 10:05:59 80 RestController.createIOU - Class "class java.sql.Timestamp" is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable"
```

here is my whitelist code:

```
class TradingAppSerializationWhitelist : SerializationWhitelist {
    // Add classes like this.
    override val whitelist = listOf(Timestamp::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For such a type, you would need to write a custom serialiser, not just whitelist the type.

However, may I ask why you want to use that type specifically? It’s more conventional to use java.time.Instant to record times on ledger when you need a time to machine precision, or the other types like java.time.LocalDateTime to record a time to human levels of precision (e.g. “8pm Tuesday” when no time zone is specified)

If you have data that’s starting from java.sql.Timestamp it’d be better to convert to an Instant, as that type has a much better design.

Additionally, timestamps are included within transactions by default. See the answer to this question to see how [In Corda, how to get the timestamp of when a transaction happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855450/in-corda-how-to-get-the-timestamp-of-when-a-transaction-happened?rq=1)